# Slope of tangent line using Wallis method

Tags: math-history

Consider the Wallis method of finding the slope of tangent lines where $x = a$.

1. Use the method to find the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $y = x^2 + 3x + 7$.
2. Use the method to find the slope of the line tangent to the graph of $y = x^4$.

Thanks for the help.